# mysqli_num_rows fails with prepared statement , procedural style

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I as far as I understood, the advantage of using prepared statements is to prevent SQL injections.

I managed to build queries with prepared statements using SELECT and INSERT.

But to achieve the equivalent of `select count()` , and I'm banging my head against the wall.
The PHP manual gives:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Code, Name FROM Country ORDER BY Name")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

    /* close result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

I trying to do this with prepared statement too. But maybe I shoudn't ?

This is what I'm trying:

```
$boy = 'yes';
$age   = 1;

$result = mysqli_prepare ($bdd, 'SELECT boy , age FROM photo WHERE  boy = ? AND age= ?' );

mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $result, "si", $boy , $age );
mysqli_stmt_execute( $result );

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows( $result );
printf( "Le jeu de résultats a %d lignes.\n", $row_cnt );
```

But I always get the same type of error whatever I'am trying

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\wamp\www\page.com\pic.php on line 36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `mysqli_stmt_num_rows` in combination with `mysqli_stmt_store_result` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

```
<?php
$boy = 'yes';
$age   = 1;

$result = mysqli_prepare ($bdd, 'SELECT boy , age FROM photo WHERE  boy = ? AND age= ?' );

mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $result, "si", $boy , $age );
mysqli_stmt_execute( $result );

// You may need this too...
mysqli_stmt_store_result( $result );

$row_cnt = mysqli_stmt_num_rows( $result );
printf( "Le jeu de résultats a %d lignes.\n", $row_cnt );
?>
```

Comment: You're right ! Need to use : mysqli_ **stmt** _store_result( $result ); **and** mysqli_ **stmt** _num_rows($result);  Thanks a lot.